# linux ssh key use in puttygen return error

Tags: linux, ssh, putty

I have this file `id_rsa`:

ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDTiVnCW4e59HeLtIdpuzgqiynTth1C+PfEMfGb7k9f1qpeSfwOuENNHlON21Vkcz5ppUh03+d4wuD7RnV8F+sTQqc`delete part of chars`fk6ORShdkrrqG6H5VOsMBJmke41SXG8ltUJh+kAJJFJ7QtER1JHAGUUIv5RIDu2d2QjAw7ogpeXSgoJAol0spWHobv1+JmPk/GcPfRPzfbFzS7oviGLiuHeu+Oro3R0P merrymaker14@mxxx-System-Product-Name

But PuTTy Key Generator if I try load this kay return me error `not a private key`. What's the matter?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is `id_rsa.pub` (public key).
`id_rsa` (private key) something like:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEowIBAAKCAQEA0/RhRTMp78Z7V84Y7zE4geLA+ZLb94Rokg8uc4xtdATXT/pF
MIGLD3wOEPM8CzTKGO08dBCNH+OSuxqTC+h/sjPjTjrtuyTvhw1Po4PJTmjvKtHm
5VE.............................................................
FLaaTQKBgBZNGBIAgszmbOwLKZz7J3mZTI/ev63VA02GLFdIXyqnKF3EWYP7Wpxc
oq/PWLpkWsT/G8RRJ7a+GapCCciF8P7x59xIDD2p9YzqZl5KrlewiacOcvMB9MBt
//1yfL8QOnlPhHbwmG7Vnsf+L8GnGzDqDOEffR3NtCnTI4V11Nmo
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```